# How to populate ArrayList with SQL Select Statement Results

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I am doing an sql select statement on my web service in Visual Studio 2010. It is only from a column but there are multiple rows of data. How do I populate an arraylist with the data and return it?

```
[WebMethod]
        public List<String> getAccType(string bankId)
        {

            myConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT TypeName FROM AccType where BankID = '" + bankId + "'", myConnection);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            List<String> AccType = new List<string>();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string iAccType = myReader["TypeName"].ToString();
                AccType.Add(iAccType);

            }
            return AccType;

        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you fetch the data, using what? Pure ado.net or some orm perhaps? Here's how you work with an ArrayList: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Return the array list from where?

Comment: I would avoid using an ArrayList and, instead, use a strongly-typed `List<T>` containing the data. Especially since all the data is coming from the same column this should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

While you could return an `ArrayList`, it would be better to return a strongly-typed collection, either a `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` with an underlying `List<T>` collection, perhaps.

Here is an example using a `SqlDataReader` to extract data from a column and populate such a list.  Note: I haven't included any error handling.

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetOrderIds()
{
    var ids = new List<int>();
    var queryString = "SELECT OrderID FROM dbo.Orders;";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                var id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                ids.Add(id);
             }
        }
    }

    return ids;
}
```